# Can I Used expo facebook ads npm library in react native bare project

Tags: java, android, facebook, react-native

I already tried to install with react native unimodules, but react-native unimodules can not properly install in my react native project (0.62) any other way to used Facebook ads in react-native project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [react-native-fbads](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads) but it's not very updated and maintained repo (last PR 7 months ago)...

I recommend you to try to install react-native-unimodules, yes it's a bit complicated but if you follow well their installation [steps](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/react-native-unimodules#-configure-android), it will work and it's also compatible with RN62 (I am using it on my current project)

The advantage of using expo modules in bare RN projects (like expo-apple-authentication, expo-facebook ...) is that you will use a well maintained modules (expo is a big project backed by big companies), they make updates very often and they have a good and structured documentation.